# Unable to save tex file on google drive on Mac

Tags: mac, texshop

For collaboration, I am using Google Drive to share my latex documents. However, recently I have become unable to save a tex file from within TexShop (v4.62) more than once after an edit. If I delete the file, I can save a new tex file with the same name, but cannot save changes after this.

I have all the permissions to this file, but get an error saying that the file cannot be saved. I have received a related error in the past that I cannot save "on a volume that does not support permanent version storage".

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Google Drive. This worked for about a day.

I am running mac Big Sur (11.2.3).

Comment: If you open the file with another text editor, can you save? Are you sure this is a TeXShop problem and not a Mac problem, in which case  [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com) might be more appropriate.  It seems like a Google problem, in fact. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252057263

Comment: I can open and save in both TextEdit and with vim without issue. Interestingly, after this I can save again in TexShop. Not sure why, but it has reset something, for now at least.

Comment: For what it's worth, further testing shows this to be a Google Drive problem.